# knockout js selectedOptions is not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have this code and I need to add default selected value

```
<select data-bind="options: items, optionsValue: `value`, optionsText:function(item) { return item.name},selectedOptions: selectedItems().item">
```

and I have this variable to make selected and it works if I am opening the selectedItems in advance like this

```
self.selectedItems = ko.observableArray([]);
self.selectedItems().item = ko.observable();
```

then I am adding default

```
self.selectedItems().item([self.info().item]);
```

this code is working fine, but in case when I am duing this, without making variable in advance

```
self.selectedItems().item = ko.observableArray([self.info().item]);
```

selectedOptions is not working,
can anyone tell me why it is not working? and how to solve this issue without adding a lot of variables in advance
thanks

Comment: `self.selectedItems` is an array, how can you use it like object?

Comment: like this
Array[0] ->
   item:c()
   ...
I am using this to make code short

Comment: Bind `selectedOptions: selectedItems` and add a default by using `self.selectedItems([self.info().item])` or whatever the default is

Comment: thanks, yes it should work, but to make default for other select with different options I should make new self.selectedItem2()... so I want make single self.selected().item2, item2 etc. for all selects using one array variable

Comment: If that's the case, you should make a plain object with observable arrays. I.e.: `self.selectedItems = { item1: ko.observableArray([]), item2: ko.observableArray([]) }` and bind by calling `selectedOptions: selectedItems.item1`